# Multiple CardView Elements Using Linear Layout

Tags: android, html, css, xml, android-layout

I currently have one cardview that I am trying to basically split down the middle. The photo is supposed to align to the left of the cardview, then the two text views are divided by a View on the right hand side of that same cardview. I have tried multiple solutions i.e adjusting the layout margins, orientations, layoutmargin_Right, gravity etc but can't get it working. Any help greatly appreciated thank you

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/infoCard"
            android:layout_width="390dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="464dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgInfo"
                    android:layout_width="51dp"
                    android:layout_height="89dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                    android:src="@drawable/infooooo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtFindOut"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:text="Step One: Find Out More"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgInfo"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imgInfo"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Step One"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want two columns (left column with image, right column with two text views on top of each other) or three columns (left column 50% with image, middle column 25% with text, right column 25% with text)?

Comment: @BenP. Two columns - One with image on side. On right hand side text view, then view, then text view beneath the view.

Comment: show some UI example of what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If you want a two-column view where one of the columns has multiple rows, then you can't achieve this with a single `LinearLayout`. You either need to use two `LinearLayouts` (one for the columns, and one for the rows) or you need to use a different view group, like `ConstraintLayout`.

For now, probably the simplest thing to do would be to use two LinearLayouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#caf"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fca"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#fff"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#afc"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]